# Why isn't my function to add time to my clock, working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am learning Vue.JS and for my first project I am trying to make a digital clock using Composition API, the problem I ran into is, that it seems the function won't add time for my clock.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div class="clock">
  <div class="time">
    <span>{{time}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup(){
     let clock = ref(new Date())
     let time = clock.value.toLocaleTimeString('lv-LV')

    const showLocalTime = function(){
        setInterval(
          time,1000)
    };
   
    onMounted(() => {
      showLocalTime()
    })

    return{
      time
    }

  }

}
</script>
```

I have also tried replacing `onMounted` with `onBeforeMount` but that didn't help either, could you help me understand why it isn't working?

Comment: It seems you don't add time to your clock.  SetInterval itself does not add anything to your variable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update time :

```js
const { ref, onBeforeUnmount } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup(){
    const time = ref((new Date()).toLocaleTimeString('lv-LV'))
    const updateCurrentTime = () => {
       time.value = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString('lv-LV')
    }
    const updateTimeInterval = setInterval(updateCurrentTime, 1000)
    onBeforeUnmount(() => clearInterval(updateTimeInterval))
    return { time }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="time">
      <span>{{ time }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd abstract the actual implementation inside a [`useClock()` hook](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNptUstuwjAQ/JWVLzgSOKp6o4DUx6UStz5OvqTphgaStWU7UCnKv3dNSBohbvbuzOzs2K14tFYdGxRLsfK5K20Aj6GxG01lbY0L0IKhJyyMww+qTUMBOiicqWHGtNkE1nh8rkx+GPsqHUoqeEZqyg35CA1ljXNo7HcW8J3PTFmPfJkMwFDmB3TcYkuvFNAds0r+s+Zwh/fJg6Yrg1ImsN5AXmHmRlqvlUS4plXa78pb8iVgbSvW5BsArLzNaNP2JqHrGBsLkTQCxVz0ay/qzKq9N8T5tZGuLw2vxRLOlVjjpOJdi58QrF+mqS/ymPreK+N2KZ+UY+M8UKGvF1/OnDw6FtYiSnSaOh45SZPHjbk7LK6eZMiPzInD69MgPMELe5eJCmZr8qw6Z/gWXEk7qUV1XGw/tZhkz9uvo7hkGZmMjcmrDdocLjvnlJtYG+Ca8Pds8cIbvsfIuvUPEtH9Ab0c49M=).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `clock` to be a ref since this value is not changing in the template. On the other hand `time` should be a ref since this is being updated every second.

On the interval you should update with the current Date. For that you need to call `new Date()` again in order to get the actual date otherwise you are getting the date from a second ago and updating the time with that old date.

The `onMounted` hook is not needed since you're changing only a variable.

Your `setup()` could look like this:

```js
setup() {
    let now = new Date();
    const time = ref(now.toLocaleTimeString("lv-LV"));

    setInterval(() => {
      now = new Date();
      time.value = now.toLocaleTimeString("lv-LV");
    }, 1000);

    return {
      time,
    };
  },
```

Here a working example to [play around](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-wozniak-n14qzh?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

just make time ref

```
<template>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="time">
      <span>{{ time }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    let time = ref(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('lv-LV'))
    setInterval(() => time.value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('lv-LV'), 1000)
    return { time }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="time">
      <h2>clock</h2>
      <span>{{ clock }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    let clock = ref()
    let time = () => {
      clock.value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('lv-LV')
    }

    time()

    const showLocalTime = function () {
      setInterval(
          () => {
            time()
          }, 1000)
    };

    onMounted(() => {
      showLocalTime()
    })

    return {
      clock
    }

  }

}
</script>
```